# Cómo saber el tamaño de la cabecera de un tema wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy trabajando con wordpress y quiero sacar una especie de alerta en mi página, por medio de un sortcode, que se colocará en la parte de arriba de la página; el problema es que quiero que valga para cualquier tema y no todas las cabeceras tienen el mismo alto.
La pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de recuperar ese alto de cada tema para así posicionar mi "cuadro" de alerta?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese cuadro quiero que salga arriba pero...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

queda por debajo de la cabecera y ya he probado a poner z-index

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por norma general las cabeceras se hacen dentro de `<header>`. Puedes buscar esa etiqueta y decir que cuando la encuentre pinte por encima. Si lo que buscas no es que se posicione antes (en el DOM) si no que se ponga encima, a nivel visual, tendrás que cambiar estilos y ponerle un `position`.

Comment: Con `get_custom_header();` obtienes el ancho y el alto de la imagen de encabezado de WP, mediante las propiedades `width` y `height`.

Comment: Gracias por ambas respuestas. Lo que yo quiero es sólo a nivel visual pero ya he probado con estilos y no lo he logrado. Por otra parte, ¿dónde debería llamar a la función get_custom_header()? siempre me aparece como variable indefinida.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Está solucinado. Mi error (por prudencia) fue poner el z-index al cuadro que yo mostraba pero la clave era cambiar también el del header al mínimo posible.